# Help! Code review required: Trying to show object details from an API call (parsing XML)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm pulling data from an API and filling a `UITableView` with article titles (from `Article` objects). I have that part working, as far as I can tell. Where I'm having a hard time is trying to show the details of the article when a row is touched on the table view.

I'm correctly capturing the article ID, and then I make a request out to the API to pull it's data and do a very similar thing to what I'm doing to load the articles `UITableView` in the step before. Here's my parser for getting article details:

```
// ArticleDetailParser.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Article.h"

@class Article;
@class ArticleDetailParser;

@protocol ArticleDetailParserDelegate <NSObject>
 - (void)parserDidFinish:(ArticleDetailParser *)parser;
 - (void)parser:(ArticleDetailParser *)parser didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end

@interface ArticleDetailParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
 id<ArticleDetailParserDelegate> delegate;

 NSMutableString *currentCharacters;
 Article *currentArticle;
 NSMutableArray *articlesCollection;
 NSMutableData *xmlData;
 NSURLConnection *connectionInProgress;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ArticleDetailParserDelegate> delegate;

- (void)parseUrl:(NSString *)url;
- (void)beginParsing:(NSURL *)xmlUrl;
- (Article *)detailedArticle;

@end
```

And here's the implementation:

```
// ArticleDetailParser.m
#import "ArticleDetailParser.h"

@implementation ArticleDetailParser

@synthesize delegate;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Parsing methods

- (void)parseUrl:(NSString *)url
{
 NSURL *xmlUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
 [self beginParsing:xmlUrl];
}

- (void)beginParsing:(NSURL *)xmlUrl
{
 [articlesCollection removeAllObjects];
 articlesCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:xmlUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

 // clear existing connection if there is one
 if (connectionInProgress) {
  [connectionInProgress cancel];
  [connectionInProgress release];
 }

 [xmlData release];
 xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

 // asynchronous connection
 connectionInProgress = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (Article *)detailedArticle
{
 return [articlesCollection objectAtIndex:0];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSXMLParserDelegate methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
 [xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"article"]) {
  currentArticle = [[Article alloc] init];
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"id"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 } 
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"alphabetical_title"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"body"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"body_html"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"category"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"authors"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"last_updated"]) {
  currentCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  return;
 }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
 [currentCharacters appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"article"]) {
  [articlesCollection addObject:currentArticle];
  [currentArticle release], currentArticle = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"id"]) {
  [currentArticle setArticleID:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"]) {
  [currentArticle setTitle:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"alphabetical_title"]) {
  [currentArticle setAlphabeticalTitle:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"body"]) {
  [currentArticle setBody:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"body_html"]) {
  [currentArticle setBodyHtml:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"category"]) {
  [currentArticle setCategory:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"authors"]) {
  [currentArticle setAuthors:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
 if ([elementName isEqual:@"last_updated"]) {
  [currentArticle setLastModified:currentCharacters];
  [currentCharacters release], currentCharacters = nil;
  return;
 }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
 [parser setDelegate:self];

 [parser parse];
 [parser release];

 [delegate parserDidFinish:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [currentArticle release];
 currentArticle = nil;

 [currentCharacters release];
 currentCharacters = nil;

 [articlesCollection release];
 articlesCollection = nil;

 [connectionInProgress release];
 connectionInProgress = nil;

 [xmlData release];
 xmlData = nil;

 NSLog(@"connection failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

 [delegate parser:self didFailWithError:error];
}

@end
```

Does anything stand out at you as being wrong? Here's my controller where I'm making use of the `ArticleDetailParser`:

```
// ArticleDetailViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ArticleDetailParser.h"

@class Article;

@interface ArticleDetailViewController : UIViewController <ArticleDetailParserDelegate> {
 Article *article;
 UILabel *aTitle;
 UILabel *aCategory;
 UILabel *aAuthors;
 UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) Article *article;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;

- (void)loadArticleDetail;
- (void)showArticle;

@end
```

And the implementation of said controller:

```
// ArticleDetailViewController.m
#import "ArticleDetailViewController.h"

@implementation ArticleDetailViewController

@synthesize article, activityView;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark init and dealloc

- (id)init
{
 [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

 [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Article Details"]; 

 article = [[Article alloc] init];

 aTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 25)];
 aCategory = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 25)];
 aAuthors = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 25)];

 activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
 [[self activityView] sizeToFit];
 [[self activityView] setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)];

 return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
 return [self init];
}

- (void)dealloc {
 [article release];
 [aTitle release];
 [aCategory release];
 [aAuthors release];
 [activityView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Web Service methods

- (void)loadArticleDetail
{
 NSString *urlToRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://wvencyclopedia.org/articles/%@.xml", [[self article] articleID]];
 ArticleDetailParser *aDetailParser = [[ArticleDetailParser alloc] init];
 [aDetailParser setDelegate:self];
 [aDetailParser parseUrl:urlToRequest]; 
 [aDetailParser release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark ArticleDetailParserDelegate methods

- (void)parserDidFinish:(ArticleDetailParser *)parser
{
 article = [parser detailedArticle]; 
 [[self activityView] stopAnimating];
}

- (void)parser:(ArticleDetailParser *)parser didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fetch failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];

 UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [actionSheet showInView:[[self view] window]];
 [actionSheet autorelease]; 
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIView methods

- (void)showArticle
{
 [aTitle setText:[[self article] title]];
 [[self view] addSubview:aTitle];
 [aTitle release];

 [aCategory setText:[[self article] category]];
 [[self view] addSubview:aCategory];
 [aCategory release];

 [aAuthors setText:[[self article] authors]];
 [[self view] addSubview:aAuthors];
 [aAuthors release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIViewController methods

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [self loadArticleDetail];
 [[self activityView] startAnimating];
 [self showArticle];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]]; 
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)loadView
{
 [super loadView];

 UIBarButtonItem *loadingView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[self activityView]];
 [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:loadingView];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```

This is my first *real* iPhone application outside of tutorials in books, and I'm new to Objective-C as well, so I could easily be misunderstanding the memory management aspects, as well as getting labels on the view.

What's happening is I click on the table view to load an article, and for the first one it will display the article title only. Then I go back, try to click another and it crashes.

I'm sorry to post this much code, but I figured if someone chooses to help it might be best to have the whole picture.

Thanks SO much in advance, if you should take on such a task!

Comment: You should try debugging this yourself for a while before posting all of your code. Use XCode's Run and Debug options and use the log to review the stack trace when your app crashes. You can also drop NSLog()s in your code to make sure your variables contain what you think they should contain. If you get any error messages that you can't quite decipher let us know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your app is crashing could be due to your UILabels getting deallocated when you release them in showArticle:.
You'll want to use 
`@property (nonatomic, retain)`
 instead of 
`@property (nonatomic, assign)`
 when dealing with objects (variable types that require the star in front of the name). Use `assign` for primitive types like integers and doubles.